# How can I reduce the size of the model created by preProcess in R

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to do preprocessing on a 1GB (1.7M rows x 77 cols) data.frame in R using the caret preProcess function, methods=c("scale", "center", "YeoJohnson").  The model it creates is 22GB in size!  Is this suppose to happen?  If so is there any way to reduce the size of the model?

`require(caret)
    set.seed(123)
    m <- 10000 # I have about 500,000
    n <- 80
    df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(m*n), nrow=m, ncol=n))
    naCutoffs <- rnorm(n)-0.8
    for (i in 1:(n*0.75))
        df[df[,i]<naCutoffs, i] <- NA
    print(mean(is.na(df)))
    pp <- preProcess(df, method=c("YeoJohnson", "center", "scale", "bagImpute"))
    print(object.size(pp), units="Gb")`

Comment: Is this being done within your call to `train`? Show some code, `str(data)` and/or give a reproducible example.

Comment: It is being done by a call to the preProcess function, not train.  I don't think I can attach the str output, it is taking minutes just to list it, there is no way it would get under the 500 character limit.  I'll add a reproducible example above.  It mimics the structure of my data file fairly well.

Comment: One other thing to note.  The size of the object seems to change sometimes when it is saved in the .rdata file although that may just be the reported size, the .rdata file often doesn't seem to correspond to the reported sizes of its objects (half the size to several multiples larger)

Comment: Unless you specify otherwise, an .rdata object will be compressed.

Comment: In fact it is the size of the object reported in R is changing between being saved and between being reloaded.  But I'm not sure how accurately it is being reported, especially since the size of the .rdata file is often a multiple of the size of the objects in it.